# How to access the HttpServletResponse from a custom CAS AuthenticationHandler to generate a cookie? in

Tags: cookies, cas

I have a CAS 3.5.2 and a welcome web application installed in my JBOSS 4.

I have written a custom AuthenticationHandler by implementing the interface:

org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.AuthenticationHandler.

My AuthenticationHandler authenticates correctly but in case the authentication is correct I would like to generate a cookie with the response.addCookie method. So I would need have access to the HttpServletResponse. The problem is that the only information I'm receiving in the authenticate method is the [Credentials credentials] parameter.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the authentication handler is only given credentials as input parameter. Though, you can use the `ExternalContextHolder` object (from the SpringWebflow) to get a `ServletExternalContext` from which you will get the `HttpServletRequest`...

Comment: Great answer, worked for me:

`HttpServletResponse response
                    = (HttpServletResponse) ExternalContextHolder.getExternalContext().getNativeResponse();`

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found 2 solutions.

At first, I added a filter in the web xml that put the response in the ThreadLocal and it was retrieved from the AuthenticationHandler.

One day, looking for another thing I found a easier way:

HttpServletResponse res=WebUtils.getHttpServletResponse(RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext());

I hope it is useful to someone else.

Comment: HttpServletResponse res=WebUtils.getHttpServletResponse(RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext()); worked like a charm. This saved my day.